# Center a div which containts floating divs

Tags: css, html, css-float, center

I have this code:

```
<div id="cuerpo">
<?php foreach ($sistemas as $cada) { ?>
    <div id="show">
        <a href="<?php echo "index.php?zona=acceso&id=" . $cada['id']; ?>" target="_self"><?php echo $cada['nombre']; ?></a>
        <p><?php echo $cada['descripcion']; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

So I have a `div` with id `"cuerpo"` that will simulate a box that contain all `$sistemas` in each `div` called `"show"`.

Then, I have this css:

```
#cuerpo
{
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border: solid 2px black;
}
#show
{
width: 200px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
border: solid 1px black;
padding: 5px;
}
```

And if I use `float: left;` everything inside my webpage will be unconfigured and very awful.

I want something like this:

[image]

PS: Everything in my `scheme` it's working but not the floating thing.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT1:**

I post an image with my actual problem according to the accepted answer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `display:inline-block` for your `#show` container. See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLp3Y/

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**EDIT*****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

If you need to use `float` you must set the parent container to `overflow:hidden`. See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLp3Y/4/

Comment: Thanks for your time @otinanai, check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/GLp3Y/2/ about to figure out to fix it?, I mean if a long description other `show` will be displayed on bottom not on top.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having troubles with the last solution @otinanai, I posted an edit of my question if you can still help I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
#cuerpo{
margin-left : 10%
margin-right : 10%}
```

that will center it

or you can put it in a div, make this div full-width and use text-align:center and the div and display:inline on the cuerpo

Comment: My problem is, if I don't have any `floating div`, `#cuerpo` will be centered, but when I float `#show` etc... everything rip off

Comment: and with the first solution?
so, you want floating divs inside a floating div?
actually, I dont see the problem, if you use float, it will float INSIDE the parent div , here the cuerpo, and so whereever is the cuerpo

Comment: @otinanai solution was the perfect asnwer, you can check his link, thanks for your time.